# Need to Display Information that Has Been Sorted Out

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am still rather new to Crystal Reports and have what feels like a pretty basic question.  I work at a school, and part of my duties are to help with donation reporting.  My boss wants a report that gives her biographical(irrelevant to this) information about donors that gave 500 or more to our Booster fund(relevant).

The kicker is this: After using record select to sort for donors who have given more than 500 to this fund, I need to show how much they have given to other funds as well.  The way I've tried to do it has given Crystal parameters to only display the data if giving exceeds 500 to booster fund.  Here's the record select:

```
{gift.fiscal_yr} = 2015 and
{gift.campaign} = "Booster" and
{gift.amount} >= 500
```

After it runs through that, when I put {gift.campaign} on the actual report, it only shows "Booster", and not any others.  I want it to show me the giving amount of all funds only if the donor has given 500 or more to Booster.

Thanks in advance for your help!  This community is a life saver!

Comment: Remove booster from record selection

Comment: I need the report to show me what they've given to all funds only if they have given 500 or more to Booster, though.

Comment: Is booster a common component in all funds? Can you show us sample data

Comment: I can't really give sample data as I don't have access to the backend, but I can give you an idea of how it's laid out.  {gift.campaign} is where all of our different fund types live, so it contains names like "Booster", "Annual", "Capital", etc.  I need the report to find donors who have given 500 or more to Booster and put them on the report.  From there, I need it to show what they've given to all the funds.  The current record selection is causing it not to display the other funds in the details section.  I can't think of a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head try this:

Take booster out of selection formula as suggested.
I assume you are grouped on donor?
Create a formula @findboosterdonor

```
if {gift.campaign} = "Booster" then 1 else 0
```

Go to Report-Selection-Formula-Group
enter this with your field names

```
sum(@findboosterdonor,{donor}) > 0
```